# cannot restore database to a different version of MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to restore a database onto a clean install of MS SQL Server 2008 R2. I am using the same installation CD as with the original computer. That PC has since died and I now need to restore the Databases onto this new computer.

When I go to restore, it says it `cannot be restored because it was created by a different version of the server (10.50.1617) than this server (10.50.6000)`

How can this be true if I used the same installation CD and don't remember updating anything?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you run some update?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [build numbers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185) you've provided, the original computer was running an updated version of SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM, while the newly installed version is SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 3.

Try removing the Service Pack and doing the restore again.

Comment: is it possible to me to upgrade the newly installed version up to the original computers build number? I roll back the original machine.

Comment: Other way around actually, you need to *downgrade* the newly installed version to SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM, so that they more closely match. The only problem is that RTM's build number is `10.50.1600` while yours is `10.50.1617`, so it's likely that the original machine had [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2494088) patch installed, as outlined in [this](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.ca/) post.